# mutate column based on grepl string match

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to mutate a column based on a partial string match, I tried:

```
df = data.frame(aa = 1:10, bb = NA, cc = 5)

df %>%
  mutate(c = ifelse(is.na(bb), grepl('a', names(.)), cc))
```

However I'm looking for something like this:

```
## if bb is na return values in aa

 aa bb cc  c
1   1 NA  5  1
2   2 NA  5  2
3   3 NA  5  3
4   4 NA  5  4
5   5 NA  5  5
6   6 NA  5  6
7   7 NA  5  7
8   8 NA  5  8
9   9 NA  5  9
10 10 NA  5 10
```

Which the above does not return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `dplyr` you can also use `dplyr::select` to select columns, there are lot of functions which help to select columns. It returns a dataframe and as we need a vector in `ifelse` we use `pull`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(c = ifelse(is.na(bb), select(., matches('a')) %>% pull, cc))

#   aa bb cc  c
#1   1 NA  5  1
#2   2 NA  5  2
#3   3 NA  5  3
#4   4 NA  5  4
#5   5 NA  5  5
#6   6 NA  5  6
#7   7 NA  5  7
#8   8 NA  5  8
#9   9 NA  5  9
#10 10 NA  5 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Using '.' to refer to the dataframe and using grepl within the dataframe to refer to match to columns as a solution..

```
  df %>% 
      mutate(c = ifelse(is.na(bb),.[,grepl('a',names(.))],cc))
```

Your code was correct, except that it identified a column name but did not refer to the column vector of the same length as `is.na(bb)` which was required for `ifelse(.,.,.). In R there are two meanings of the word "name" at least as far as the console is concerned. Some text flanked by two quote signs is a character value and the "names" (more specifically the column names) of a dataframe are also character values stored in an attribute. But the R workspace also has a collection ov "names" (more specifically object names) for which the typical way to get their values is to type their R names into the console *unquoted*.